# Why I cant see password prompt when .profile executes?

Tags: bash, startup, .profile, keychain

I want to use **keychain** for SSH cron jobs.
I've found this good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041092).

I've add command `keychain --nogui id_rsa` in `.profile`
And when I reboot and login I have to enter password.

But I don't see any password prompt when `.profile` executes.
I can create stand-alone bash script with the command and place it in Start-up Applications. But I'm not sure this way is good.

Where the right place for this command with **keychain** password prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.profile` get executed when you open up a terminal window, not when you log in to a desktop.

If you want to do this system wide for ALL users create a .desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`. Example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=A custom Script
Exec=sudo /sbin/my_custom_script.sh
Icon=system-run
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

and create a script.sh with your command in it. That also makes sure they can not permanently remove your desktop file. If you want this for 1 user put the script in  `~/.config/autostart/` and change the Exec line to `Exec=~/bin/acustomscript.sh`

Comment: I've got password prompt when I add additional line in Desktop Entry file: `Terminal=true`. Am I right?

Comment: Oh that will run it in a terminal yes.